# PHP Telegram Bot Не могу выводить команды с кнопок

Tags: php

Проблема является следующей, есть меню, есть инлайн кнопка с callback_data => '/registration'
однако я вызывал и через принимаемый текст от пользователя и через ['callback_query']['data']

```
use Telegram\Bot\Api;

$telegram = new Api('...');
$result = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates();

$message = $result['message'];
$iskbd = !$message;
if ($iskbd)
    $message = $result['callback_query'];
$usrtext = $message['text'];
$chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
$usrname = $message['from']['username'];
$user_id = $message['from']['id'];
$usrfirst_name = $message['from']['first_name'];
$usrlast_name = $message['from']['last_name'];
$callback_query = $result['callback_query']['id'];
$callback_data = $result['callback_query']['data'];
$cq_command = mb_strtolower($result['callback_query']['data']);
$teamlogo = 'logo.jpg';
$keyboardvalue = 'inline_keyboard';

if($user_id){
    if($usrtext == '/start'){
        if($database->get("user_id", "users", "user_id = $user_id") == false){
            $answer = [
                'Компания, приглашает вас в свою уютную команду',
                '',
                '<i>Для вступления в команду, зарегистрируйтесь в боте</i>',
            ];
            $inline_keyboard = json_encode([
                $keyboardvalue => [
                    [
                        ['text' => 'Зарегистрироватся', 'callback_data' => '/registration']
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
            $telegram->sendPhoto(['parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'photo' => $teamlogo, 'caption' => implode("\n", $answer), 'reply_markup' => $inline_keyboard]);
        }
    }
    if($cq_command == '/registration'){
        /*if($database->get("user_id", "users", "user_id = $user_id") == true){
            $answer = [
                'Вы уже зарегистрированны!',
            ];
            $inline_keyboard = json_encode([
                $keyboardvalue=>[
                    [
                        ['text' => 'Открыть меню', 'callback_data' => '/start']
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
        
            $telegram->sendMessage(['parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => implode("\n", $answer), 'reply_markup' => $inline_keyboard]);
        }
        else
        {*/
            $answer = [
                'Откуда вы узнали о нашей команде?',
            ];
            $inline_keyboard = json_encode([
                $keyboardvalue=>[
                    [
                        ['text' => 'Открыть меню', 'callback_data' => '/start']
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
            $telegram->sendMessage(['parse_mode' => 'HTML', 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => implode("\n", $answer), 'reply_markup' => $inline_keyboard]);
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($result['callback_query'])){//Если была нажата кнопка
    $chat_id = $result['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
    $callback_data = $result['callback_query']['data'];
}
```

у вас есть уже чат айди, допустим и коллбек, вы через условие проверяете: если нажата, то перезаписываете переменную таким образом.